# How to securely store HeidiSQL passwords

Tags: database, passwords, heidisql

According to [this](https://www.heidisql.com/forum.php?t=10617) HeidiSQL stores passwords obfuscated in the registry. I would like to save them in a more secure manner:
I have an encrypted VeraCrypt volume and I want HeidiSQL to only access my passwords when the volume is mounted. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just a little idea:

- use portable version of HeidiSQL
- put your HeidiSQL portable in your veraCrypt volume

this is of-course with the assumption of HeidiSQL portable does not store anything in the registry. this, you need to verify yourself by using it from a USB stick/drive from one PC to another, and see if your passwords are carried to the other PC.

Comment: That indeed worked! The portable version stores everything in a file called `portable_settings.txt`. It will however load settings from registry if the file is not found. Bonus trick: Delete `portable_settings.txt`, start portable HeidiSQL (settings will be loaded from registry), click "more->export settings to file" and call the file `portable_settings.txt` in the same directory as the portable `heidisql.exe`. Then delete the registry (HKEY_USERS\...\Software\HeidiSQL\Servers).

Comment: If you want to secure it, you can create a Windows Virtual Disk and Encrypt this file with Bitlocker. Store the Portable Version in it and all is done